# How to get battery current at an fixed interval?

Tags: android, timer, broadcastreceiver, intervals

I want to get battery Current, and Voltage at an interval of 5 seconds.

But in my source, the Voltage and Current changes at an random interval.

such as 5 seconds, 10 seconds, 9 seconds, .......

I heard BroadcastReceiver requires a return value within 10 seconds.

I guess this is a cause, but I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
package com.example.hubertlee.batterywearrate;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private TextView batteryInfo;
  Long avgCurrent = null, currentNow = null;
  int count = 0;
  float power = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BatteryManager mBatteryManager = (BatteryManager) getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);
    batteryInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBatteryInfo);
    this.registerReceiver(this.batteryinfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        avgCurrent = mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_AVERAGE);
        currentNow = mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW);
    }

}



private BroadcastReceiver batteryinfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        int health = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0);
        int icon_small = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_ICON_SMALL,0);
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);
        boolean present = intent.getExtras().getBoolean(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PRESENT);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 0);
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, 0);
        String technology = intent.getExtras().getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY);
        float temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
        float voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, 0);
        batteryInfo.setText("Health: " + health + "\n" + "Icon small : "+icon_small+"\n" +
                "Level : "+level+"\n"+"Present : "+present+"\n"+"Scale: "+
                scale+"\n"+"Status :"+status+"\n"+ "Technology:"+technology+"\n"+
                "Temperature :"+temp/10+"'C\n"+"Voltage:"+voltage/1000+"V\n"+"BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_AVERAGE = "
                + avgCurrent + "mAh"+"\n"+"BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW =  " + currentNow + "mAh"+"\n"+"count ="+count);
        count++;




    }
  };
}
```

Comment: *I heard BroadcastReceiver requires a return value within 10 seconds* from where? (seems like you misunderstood something - I bet that it was something about implkementation of `onReceive` should return in no time) *I guess this is a cause* no, it is not ... action is "ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" ... so it is sended when "BATTERY CHANGED" ... there is no need to send something if there was no changes - it's wasting of resources

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then how can I get current at interval? Is there no way? I need an fixed interval.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a code run at fix interval, take a look at Alarm manager :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Like Selvin said, the broadcast is called only when it change.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have a small question. I think a phone's voltage and current change constantly. Because the phone is using electricity irregularly. then why does it send me current and voltage one time in almost 10 seconds? They change every second, every micro second, every nano second...

Comment: It's because the system cannot sent Broadcast message often : a Broadcast message is delivered when system can. Means Broadcast message have low priority. This can explain the delay.

Comment: Ahh. I get it. Thank you so much. I've decided to use Handler because I want a screen ON. Do you happen to know how to use BatteryManager without Broadcast? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED  I think it uses Broadcast to get battery properties..?